# Identify dateformat matlab

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a way to identify the dateformat when adding a cellstr.

Thus when I run the function:

```
customFunction('2017/01/06')
```

that it returns

```
'yyyy/mm/dd'
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: How do you know it's not `yyyy/dd/mm`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `java.text.SimpleDateFormatinside` inside matlab function

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

sdf = SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd')

sdf.parse(  char('20180410') )

ans =

Tue Apr 10 00:00:00 IST 2018
```

---

You'll have to add `try ... catch..` for all possible formats and loop over each.

```
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",        "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", 
        "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", 
        "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ",     "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", 
        "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss",        
        "yyyyMMdd"
```

Comment: There's no need to use Java functions here, you could just use the built-in [`datetime`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) to the same end. What happens if there are multiple matches or if you don't account for a possible format?

Comment: @Wolfie could you please add that as an answer or provide some links, which handles the multiple matches as well ? Also there could be multiple ways to tame a cat

Comment: I don't want to answer because I don't believe the question has been well defined and you'd still have to handle multiple matches in a similar way. I included a link to the documentation in my comment. Yes but taming a  cat with native functions is the cleanest way....